# Stone-Weierstrass Theorem with two compact metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functions, metric-spaces, compactness

I currently try to prove the following:

Let $X,Y$ be compact metric spaces. $A = \{(x,y) \rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{n} f_i(x)g_i(y) \ | \ f_i \in C(X,\mathbb{R})$ and $g_i \in C(Y,\mathbb{R}), 1 \leqslant i \leqslant n \}$.

I want to prove that

(i) $A$ is an algebra and

(ii) $A$ is uniformly dense in $C(X \times Y, \mathbb{R})$.

Regarding (ii) I think I will just show that (given $A$ is an algebra) the constant functions are in $A$ and that $A$ separates points which I think is straight forward. However, I have difficulties to show that $A$ is indeed an algebra. Could someone show me how to prove this rigorously?

Comment: Step 0: Gain clarity about what you need to show. Do you know what an algebra is? Do you know that $C(X\times Y,\mathbb{R})$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra?

Comment: I am sorry if it wasn't clear enough. I know what an algebra is and I think I will have to show that $A$ is a vector space and is closed under multiplication meaning that if $x,y \in A$ then $xy \in A$. So I am just not sure how to prove it.

Comment: Okay. So you more-or-less know that you need to show that i) the sum of two elements of $A$ belongs to $A$, ii) scalar multiples of elements of $A$ belong to $A$, and iii) the product of two elements of $A$ belongs to $A$. Do you see that i) and ii) are fairly trivial?

Comment: That's my problem, I intuitively see that e.g. sums of two elements of $A$ must also be in $A$ but am not sure how I can prove that it is the case. Like if $x,y \in A$ then it must be the case that also $x+y \in A$ due to continuity.

Comment: This isn't about continuity. The elements of $A$ have a particular structure. You need to show that the sum of two has the same structure. Thus consider $$\varphi(x,y) = \sum_{i = 1}^n f_i(x)g_i(y)\quad\text{and}\quad \psi(x,y) = \sum_{k = 1}^m \tilde{f}_k(x)\tilde{g}_k(y)\,.$$ Can you see what to choose to have $$(\varphi + \psi)(x,y) = \sum_{\ell = 1}^{r} \hat{f}_{\ell}(x)\hat{g}_{\ell}(y)\,?$$

Comment: $\hat{f} = f + \tilde{f}$?

Comment: Not quite. First, take $r = n + m$. Then set $\hat{f}_{\ell} = f_{\ell}$ for $\ell \leqslant n$, and $\hat{f}_{\ell} = \tilde{f}_{\ell - n}$ for $n < \ell \leqslant r$, and similar for $\hat{g}_{\ell}$. That shows the sum of elements of $A$ has the required structure. The scalar multiples are easy. For the product, the argument is somewhat similar to the argument for the sum, but a bit more involved. Want to give it a try?

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense! And yes, for scalar multiplication it would be straight forward. I fail to see though how the argument would be different for the product. Couldn't we apply the same method to multiplication?

Comment: Well, it needs a few modifications. From a sufficiently abstract viewpoint it's the same method, from a more detail-oriented viewpoint it's a similar method.

Comment: I see. So assuming n = m = 2 and multiplying things out I would obtain something like: $[f_1(x) g_1(y) + f_2(x)g_2(y)] [\tilde{f_1}(x) \tilde{g_1}(y) + \tilde{f_2}(x) \tilde{g_2}(y)]$. I guess I would now have to multiply this out somehow and define $\hat{f_l}$ and $\hat{g_l}$ accordingly

Comment: Right. In general, you get a sum with $n\cdot m$ terms. It's easiest to index them with the pairs $(i,k)$.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help!